# Formula to return the time & date a picklist field is changed

Tags: formula, picklist

I am setting up a formula whereby when a certain field is changed (picklist field), the date & time of the last change is returned. My question is how to best capture all the picklist values?

Should  I use `ISPICKVAL/TEXT/CASE`? Also, is `ISCHANGED` necessary here?

AND

```
ISCHANGED(D2L_Status__c)
CASE(D2L_Status__c,'Draft','Draft – Queried Supplier','Draft – Under Investigation','Input',
'Input – Queried Supplier','Input – Under Investigation','Pending Live Registration',
'Pending Live – Queried Supplier','Live','Rejected by Supplier',
'Rejected by Supplier – Queried Supplier','Rejection – 2nd Request',
'Rejection – 3rd Request','Transfer Re-application Requested','Objection Reason Request Sent',
'Objection – Awaiting LOA','Objection Actioned','LOA Obtained - Objection Reason Request Sent',
'Objection – Awaiting AM/Customer Action','Objection - Awaiting AM/Customer Feedback',
'Objection – 2nd Request','Objection – 3rd Request','Re-applied for Objection','Objection Complete',
'Objection Upheld - CLPW')
```

TIA

Comment: What is the point of your case statement. Also, you will need to use a wfr and a field to track the date as the formula field will not do this. Ischanged cannot be used in a formula field

Comment: Do you want to capture a date/time stamp only when a specific picklist value set to or changed from? Please add more details for a business case

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can just use the **Field History Tracking** option and that will take care of these changes for that specific field.

From any object, you can set up to 20 fields to be tracked, click on the **Set History Tracking** on the fields section. This will also create an **Account History** related list to show those changes at the record page layout level. It will display date and time plus some extra information.

Keep in mind that every time that you change your values you need to make changes to your formulas, is a lot maintenance that will be inefficient. By using field history tracking you can forget about that.